# Emulator for LG Pro:Centric

Tags: emulator

I'm developing an app for LG Pro:Centric. But I have some troubles. Is there any emulator or debugger for LG Pro:Centric applications?

Comment: Can you add some details of what you need? What features do you consider important? Under what platform you need it running?

Comment: @Alejandro I need an emulator of a pro-centric LG TV for windows. It's something like webOS, but I don't know it is exactly webOS or not.

Comment: Have a look here for providing more information on how to ask for recommendations: https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/6957